# How to check if there's enough oplog history for a change stream start position in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

When using change streams in MongoDB you have to ability, since version 4.2, to supply e.g. an [startAtOperationTime](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#id1) token to indicate from which position the change stream should start. However, the documentation mentions this:

> The oplog must have enough history to locate the operation associated with the token or the timestamp, if the timestamp is in the past.

and this:

> Starting in MongoDB 4.0, you can specify a startAtOperationTime to open the cursor at a particular point in time. If the specified starting point is in the past, it must be in the time range of the oplog.

Is there a way to figure out whether the oplog has enough history to start at the `BsonTimestamp` supplied to the `startAtOperationTime` or the `BsonValue` used with a `startAt` operation?

**Update**

Unfortunatley it doesn't seem like I get an exception using `startAtOperationTime` with a `BsonTimestamp` that is older than the first oplog entry. For example, if I use `BsonTimestamp(0)` it seems like it just starts at the first available entity in the oplog (at least when using the MongoDB Java Driver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your user account has read permission on the oplog.rs collection in the local database, you can query the oplog directly.

From the shell to get the epoch timestamp of the first oplog entry:

```
db.getSiblingDB("local").oplog.rs.findOne().ts.getTime()
```

Comment: And if there's no access to "local", is it then impossible?

Comment: The oplog is stored in the local database, so that would be the only way to read it directly.  If you don't have access to the local database, you might be able to infer it from the "oplog window" metric, if you have access to the metrics.

Comment: Maybe it's out of scope, but how can I find the "oplog window" metric?

Comment: I see it as one of the choices on Atlas' metrics (might be only visible for paid plans)

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a change stream from that time. If you receive an error, your oplog isn't long enough.

Comment: Which exception is thrown?

Comment: For example if I use "startAtOperationTime" with a BsonTimesamp of 0 I don't seem to get an exception, it'll just start at the first available oplog position.

Comment: Maybe there is no way to know then.

Comment: And you should add that to the question.